# don't work: remove style attribute or change width\height css property via jquery in IE6\IE7\IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

How remove style attribute or change width\height CSS property via jQuery in IE6\IE7\IE8?

Don't work:

```
$(e).css({'width': '', 'height': ''});
$(e).removeAttr('style');
e.removeAttribute('style');
```

**Update:**

e is native object of DOM. Firebug tell me that element exists

In first function i add width\height, in second remove.

in other browser all ok

Don't work:

```
$(e).css({'width': 'auto', 'height': 'auto'});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to remove width and height? If you're trying to make it disappear then you should just do $(e).hide(); and $(e).show(); or you can do $(e).width(0).height(0); Removing the attributes is unnecessary.

Comment: We need to see how `e` is defined. Is it a jQuery object? Is it inside a `function(e)` from a `.click()` call for example?

Comment: what do you mean with don't work What is 'e'?Is it working in other browsers?

Comment: Are you trying to get it to revert to the css defined value (might work but may also be buggy), or somehow remove the value it has inherited from it's css class (this won't work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to set the width and height back to the whatever is defined in css?

In theory what you do should work (unless there's some jquery specific issues which I'm not aware of), but I think IE won't accept empty string as a valid value and may keep the value unchanged.

The most foolproof way to do it, is to store the original value before you change it the first time (unless this is a generic effect that should be applied to an undefined amount of elements, this should not be too hard) and set it back to that value instead of clearing it.

If the original value is a calculated value such as percentage (of the screen width etc.) you may have to recalculate it or set it to a hardcode percentage value since you may not be able to get the original css value, only the calculated pixel value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to set the [`width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property) and [`height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property) properties to their "initial value".

The initial value for both properties is `auto`, so this will work:

```
$(e).css({
    'width': 'auto',
    'height': 'auto'
});
```

I tested this in IE6, and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/BNrgF/

Comment: It was just an educated guess based on the **minimal amount of information** you provided. You've evidently sorted the problem out, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Excellent, a blank string didn't work and my memory failed me; I appreciate the tip of using 'auto'.